# pfsense Captive Portal redirect to <ip>:8000/$PORTAL_ACTION$

Tags: pfsense, captive-portal

Something is wrong when I try to replace the portal login page with a customized one. After the sign in button is clicked, I was redirected to: (server IP):8000/$PORTAL_ACTION$. What is this $PORTAL_ACTION$ thing, and how do I determine it?